# R: find data frame index of multiple conditions

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset, min

Given two data frames `s` and `q` with five observations each:

```
set.seed(8)
s <- data.frame(id=sample(c('Z','X'), 5, T),
                t0=sample(1:10, 5, T), 
                t1 = sample(11:30, 5, T))

q <- data.frame(id=sample(c('Z','X'), 5, T),
                 t0=sample(1:10, 5, T), 
                 t1 = sample(11:30, 5, T))


> s
  id t0 t1
1  Z  8 20
2  Z  3 12
3  X 10 19
4  X  8 21
5  Z  7 13

> q
  id t0 t1
1  X  3 30
2  Z  5 12
3  Z  7 23
4  Z  3 21
5  X  7 27
```

The midpoint for the observations between the variables t0 and t1 is (e.g. for `s` data):

```
s$t0+(s$t1-s$t0)/2
```

To find the index of the (first) observation in `s` whose midpoint is closest to, say, the first observation in `q` I can do:

```
i <- which.min(abs((s$t0+(s$t1-s$t0)/2 - (q$t0[1]+(q$t1[1]-q$t0[1])/2)))
s[i,]
```

gives:

```
    id t0 t1
3  X 10 19
```

But I cannot figure out how to find the same index in the original data `s` if I also want to condition on the id variable (e.g. pseudo code like: `which.min(....) & s$id == q$id[1]` - in this case the midpoint is sought among ids being 'X'). This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644912/select-index-of-data-frame-statisfying-multiple-conditions-in-r) is close but not spot on.
Again: I need a index to be used in the original 5-row data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `which.min` argument to infinity when your condition is not obeyed:

```
val <- abs((s$t0+(s$t1-s$t0)/2 - (q$t0[1]+(q$t1[1]-q$t0[1])/2))
val[s$id != q$id[1]] <- Inf
i <- which.min(val)
```

By the way, you can simplify the expression in the first character as:

```
val <- abs((s$t0+s$t1)/2-(q$t0[1]+q$t1[1])/2)
```

or even

```
val <- abs(s$t0+s$t1-q$t0[1]-q$t1[1])/2
```